# Associating an independent ajax request to a targeted element with the same group class name in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I press any of the buttons that have the same class name they all activate the same AJAX request so how can I activate a request independently for a particular button that has the same class

name I use the ***this*** keyword on this but I can not get it to work properly with this so I reverted back with out the **this** keyword. I constructed the code like this for simplicity for this post.

Here is the code

**index.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendRequest').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'x.php',
            success: function(result){
                $('.responseContainer').html(result)
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>

<button class='sendRequest'>Go</button>
<div class='responseContainer'></div>
<br>

<button class='sendRequest'>Go</button>
<div class='responseContainer'></div>
<br>

<button class='sendRequest' >Go</button>
<div class='responseContainer'></div>
```

**x.php**

```
<h1>The Ajax Request was sent by this button</h1>
```

Comment: Why do you put same class in all three buttons? Is it a restriction? If not, there is a very bad layout design...

Comment: @ClownCoder it's not I said this is based on a simple example for complexity. Don't take this as my literal code it's just for us people to use so we can integrate in more complicated code. Either your missing the point of my post or you skipped thru my whole post with out reading everything. But I respect what your saying so how would you do this in a code example?

Comment: I apologize if my comment sounds rude, it wasn't my intention. I read all your post, and I understood the concept of having many elements with same class binding same event but doing different things. This is a bit rare. But if you need just inject ajax's response in each div.responseContainer close to the button who fired the event. then the answer given by Pedro Martins is the way to go. But I insist, isn't a very good way to do it. Cleaner markup is cleaner javascript, better performance and lot less js trickery or workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must find the next sibling that matches the class responseContainer.

This is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendRequest').click(function(){
        var $container = $(this).next('.responseContainer');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'x.php',
            success: function(result){
                $container.html(result)
            }
        });
        });
    });
});
```